# Unable to connect to ADB server

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Previously I was able to connect Android Studio to Samsung Galaxy S4 and muz uPAD tablet. But then I encountered ADB problem. it says ADB is not responding.

Now I cannot connect Android Studio to my tablet or phone..

I tried re-installing Android Studio and tablet driver all over again. But still no connection to any of my devices.

What is the problem here ?

Comment: try `adb kill-server` then `adb devices` on your terminal

Comment: Did you try restarting the pc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems This was not Android Studio problem. I had installed PC to Android file transfer software called Moborobo in my PC and this software prevented Android Studio from connecting to my tablet when I ran Android Studio. When I uninstalled this, Android Studio connected to tablet without any problem. But it was really hard and had to do lot of trials to find out what was the problem.

Answer (score 8):

If you are working on windows then you can manually connect to adb.

1. **Kill the adb process from windows task manager.**
2. **Go to C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe.**

Double click on adb.exe. I think that might help you.

Comment: AppData would be hidden therefore you have to first select - show hidden files

Comment: console command - adb.exe start-server

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It said " Cannot connect to ADB server . Attempting to reconnect" and the "Loading devices" was forever loading. Its because the adb server is blocked by your antivirus. Check if there's an "adb.exe" file in your "Android/Sdk/platform-tools" folder. If yes, then its your antivirus causing the issue. It worked well when I disabled it.
If not this, you might wanna try enabling "Virtual Machine Platform" on your "Windows Features" and make sure "Windows Hypervisor Platform" is disabled. You may have to reboot your laptop after this. This may work depending on your pc config.

Mine worked when I tried both.. Its more probably the antivirus..

Answer (score 0):

This could be some configuration problem with you android studio try to delete your .android file in your users folder and restart android studio(proceed with caution).first try with android emulator, make sure to keep your android sdk up to date. give some to android studio in first initialization.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an issue with ADB server on Ubuntu 22.04. Issue's log output was:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
Adb connection Error:EOF
Unable to open connection to ADB server: java.io.IOException: Can't find adb server on port 5037, IPv4 attempt: Connection refused, IPv6 attempt: Connection refused
Failed to start monitoring 1B151FDEE006P8
Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
```

Starting ADB server manually resolved the issue:

```bash
# Navigate to Android SDK platform-tools directory.
cd {androidSdkDirectory}/platform-tools

# Start ADB server manually.
./adb start-server
```

Output of the last command:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```